# Can I assign Address of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, pointers, variables

In PHP I want to assign address of variable, like in C Language we use * pointer to assign or store address of any variable. In php the variable address assigning system is possible or not?

Comment: PHP doesn't have pointers. Maybe what you really want is a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: References are things that exist, but they're not pointers and you probably shouldn't use them like they are. You should state the problem you're currently having rather than asking about the problem you're having with the solution you're trying to apply.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the pointer address but you can use references

> $var1 = &$var2